# Why do I need to relaunch dkpg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration after every startup?

Tags: keyboard-layout

I've switched recently to an UK keyboard, from a FR keyboard. It is an usb keyboard, and first I plugged it in, I had to launch `dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration` in order to request the correct layout (ie: uk).

But after every reboot of the machine, the laytout comes back to the FR layout. How can I make the modification persisting?

I am using Ubuntu, running the Stump Window Manager. And here is the `/etc/default/keyboard` at any time (that is right after startup, and before and after I run the `dpkg-reconfigure` tool)

```
XKBMODEL="hhk"
XKBLAYOUT="gb"
XKBVARIANT=""
XKBOPTIONS="terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp"
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you need to relaunch dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration after every startup.

But maybe you can add the required commands to `/etc/rc.local` before the `exit 0` line, that way it will get excecuted automatically on launch.

Until someone finds a better solution.

Comment: Try my other answer first.

Comment: I am wondering whether that could work. It looks like dpkg-reconfigure is heavily relying on a human input for proceeding.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried editing

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/keyboard
```

and then change to

```
XKBLAYOUT="uk"
```

So uk insteak of gb. Make sure you save and then this change should persist after reboot.

Comment: That did not worked out for me.